# 3d matrix multiplied by a 2d matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Edit:

There are one 3-d matrix $A = [ A_1 \ A_2 \ ... \ A_K]\in\mathbb{R}^{K\times D\times K}$ and $A_i\in\mathbb{R}^{D\times K},i=1,...,K$, and a 2d matrix $B = [B_1 \ B_2 \ ... \ B_k ]\in\mathbb{R}^{K \times K}$, where $B_i = [b_{1i},...,b_{Ki}]$. What I want to get is $C = [A_1 B_1, A_2 B_2, ..., A_K B_K] \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times K}$. How can I do this using tensor product? I am a little confused about the dimension coordination.

Comment: With arrays of dimension 3 or more, there is no standard notation for matrix "multiplications". Instead, it is common to write out the sum using Einstein summation notation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hi, I edited to show the problem more clearly. I am confused about how to coordinate these dimensions by tensor product. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what "do this using tensor product" is supposed to mean. However, we can write the desired tensor in summation form. Let $A_{i,j,k}$ denote the $i,j$ entry of the matrix $A_k$, and let $B_{i,j}$ denote the $i$th entry of $b_j$.  We can write that for $1 \leq j \leq D$ and $1 \leq k \leq K$, the $j,k$ entry of $C$ is given by
$$
C_{j,k} = \sum_{p=1}^K A_{j,p,k} B_{p,k}.
$$
We could express this matrix as a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction) of the $D \times K \times K \times K$ tensor $\tilde C$ with entries
$$
\tilde C_{j,k,p,q} = A_{j,p,k}B_{q,k}.
$$
Neither $C$ nor $\tilde C$ can be expressed as the "tensor product" of $A$ and $B$ in the conventional sense. If you insist on relating this to a tensor product somehow, then you might find it notable that we can write
$$
\tilde C_{j,k,p,q} = (A \otimes B)_{j,p,k,q,k}.
$$
In other words, $\tilde C$ consists of the "diagonal elements" of the tensor product $A \otimes B$.